# Foreign keys issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I have a table created using the query

```
CREATE TABLE branch_dim (  
   branch_id numeric(18,0) NOT NULL,  
   country_name varchar(30),  
   island_name char(30),    
   region_name varchar(30),  
   branch_name varchar(30),  
   region_manager varchar(30),  
   marketing_manager varchar(30),  
   branch_manager varchar(30),  
   promoter_main varchar(30),   
   promoter_other varchar(30),  
   PRIMARY KEY (branch_id,island_name)   
 ) ON branch_dim_scheme(island_name)
```

Now I have another table

```
CREATE TABLE order_fact (  
   branch_id numeric(18,0) NOT NULL,  
   product_id numeric(18,0) NOT NULL,  
   order_id numeric(18,0) NOT NULL,  
   day_id numeric(18,0) NOT NULL,  
   FOREIGN KEY (branch_id) REFERENCES branch_dim (branch_id),  
)
```

First query has partition in it that is why I have 2 primary keys. Now if I run the second query I am getting the error

> "There are no primary keys or
>   candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'branch_dim' that matches the
>   reference column list in the foreign
>   key 'FK_order_fac_branc_10234AD'"

What might be the problem ?

Comment: It would be helpful to know which database this is for as the answer may be differnt depending onteh specific db.

Comment: oops!! sorry !! it is sql server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table has a composite primary key :

```
CREATE TABLE branch_dim (

PRIMARY KEY (branch_id,island_name)
```

Hence, any foreign key reference to that table **also** must use both elements for its foreign key (you need to reference *the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key* - so help you Codd :-):

```
CREATE TABLE order_fact (  
   branch_id numeric(18,0) NOT NULL,  
   island_name char(30),
   product_id numeric(18,0) NOT NULL,  
   order_id numeric(18,0) NOT NULL,  
   day_id numeric(18,0) NOT NULL,  

   FOREIGN KEY (branch_id, island_name) 
     REFERENCES branch_dim (branch_id, island_name)
```

Word of advice: for anything longer than 5 character or so, I would **never** use `CHAR(x)` as the data type - this will create a field that is **always** 30 characters long - whether you store that many chars in it or not. If you store less, the value is padded with spaces to the defined length (30 chars).

For anything larger than 5 or so characters, I would recommend to **always** use `VARCHAR` instead !

Same goes for `numeric(18,0)` : for an `ID` field, I would always use `INT` - much nicer, cleaner, smaller, just plain better!

Comment: Here the problem is i should not add island_name in the order_fact table. The order_fact table is like data dictionary.

Comment: I can reduce the primary key to one instead of two. But the problem is with partition. I have done the partition in "island_name" field so is there any way to do the same with single key(branch_id alone) ?

Comment: @deepak: what do you mean by "partition" ??

Comment: Like for example in the table branch_dim for the field island_name possible values are "North Island" and "South Island". What I have done is i have partitioned the table into two parts. One partition has all records with island_name value "North Island" and other with "South Island".

Comment: @Deepak: ok, that partitioning won't be affected - and the partition key doesn't need to be part of the primary key (as far as I know)....

Answer (score 4):

You've defined the primary key on branch_dim as a composite primary key made up of branch_id and island_name. When you create order_fact, you're trying to reference only branch_id as your foreign key.

Comment: so what should I do ? do i need to add the island_name field in the second table ? is there any other way to do that without having island_name added into the second table ?

Comment: That's a somewhat larger database design question, that would take really understanding what you're trying to do in order to answer it. However, there are certainly some options. First, if you're really trying to uniquely identify a row in branch_dim, the foreign key needs to be the same as the primary key, so you would need to add a similar column to order_fact. If branch_id is enough to accurately identify a row in branch_dim, you could modify that table structure to only use branch_id as the primary key. It really does depend on how you plan on structuring and identifying your data.

Comment: I think you should take some time to learn about indexes, primary and foreign keys, and clustered indexes. This article, http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020522.htm, might help a little, but of largest concern to me is that you're using numeric for ids.

Comment: @Deepak - you just need to add a `UNIQUE` constraint to `branch_id` in `branch_dim`. Then you should be able to create `order_fact`.

Comment: @Dante617 -  Actually the table order_fact is fact table and i am linking the dimension table by using foreign key. I have a partition on branch_dim which is done on branch_dim.island_name. Is there any way to reduce the number of primary keys in branch_dim(first table) ? I should not lose the partition by the way.

Comment: @Paul Spangle  - I can reduce the primary key to one instead of two. But the problem is with partition. I have done the partition in "island_name" field so is there any way to do the same with single key(branch_id alone) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the primary key of branch_dim just branch_id and add an index on island_name. Also, are you branch_ids really numeric(18, 0)? If so I would make a surrogate primary key (something that can be auto incremented, int or bigint, identity).

As it is, your primary key (and thus clustered index) is very wide. This will degrade performance and I'm guessing, in your scenario, fragment your clustered index (bad).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making the primary key field (branch_id) as NONCLUSTERED and UNIQUE and made the island_name field as  and so i had only one primary key and my partition key is island_name. This solved my problem. Thanks all for the help..